# New Line not working properly in Angular 2 editable div

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have a contenteditable div that works great until I assign the changed text back into initial variable.  When editing and I press enter, a new line appears properly in the editable div, but does not get stored into 'name'.  The next character typed ends up at the end of the previous line, and the cursor goes to the beginning of the first line.  If I remove the (input) line, the div behaves properly, but 'name' is not updated.  How do I get the div to behave properly and update 'name'?

[Plunk Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/XaHsSRcfieKI8VU6TjTf/)

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div style="white-space: pre-wrap;"
         [textContent]=name
         (input)="name=$event.target.textContent" 
      contenteditable>
    </div>
    <div style="white-space: pre-wrap;">{{name}}</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `TEST`
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule  ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ] 
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Expected Result:

```
Test
Test
```

Actual Result:

```
estTestT
```

Comment: The problem is that `name` updates the control once you press `enter`. I would write my own value accessor for `div` and use formControl from reactive forms module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some little changes you can make it work.

- Change textContent attribute to `innerText`.
- Set the the innerText value value in `ngOnInit` and forgo ngModel.

**Typescript:**

```
@ViewChild('myEditable') private myEditable;
name:string;
constructor() {
  this.name = 'I am editable';
}
ngOnInit(){
  this.myEditable.nativeElement.innerText = this.name;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div #myEditable contentEditable (input)="name=$event.target.innerText"></div>
<div style="white-space:pre">{{name}}</div>
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzpqtc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: If you wish to forgo the 'Viewchild' reference, you can add a directive that will set the value of the element on directive ngOnInit. A little bit neater?

Comment: It doesn't work properly because if you put 2 lines feed, one of these is doubled..  (we have 3 lines feed istead of 2)   :(

Comment: @nonozor, the post is really old and I forgot what it was about. could you explain what's going on?